# Static content deploy not working

Tags: command-line, magento2

I have setup a website on server and configured all things. The website works on browser and I am able to navigate on other links.
When I tried to deply the content from command line `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` it showing below error and failed the process.

```
[Exception]                                                                  
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away in /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

Your early answers is really very appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like mysql isn't running on the server. Did you check it using `service mysqld status` or `ps aux | grep mysqld` ?

Comment: Thanks for comment but website running on browser..

Answer (score 1):

Go to MySQL configuration (in /etc/my.cnf). Add

```
[mysqld]

innodb_file_per_table = OFF
```

then restart the MySQL server